# try to log into a simple course website using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, web-crawler, python-requests

I'm trying to use python to log into one of my course page.

I use httpFox to detect the login page and the post data. I dont know why, but i keep getting error saying:

> SE 3X03 / CS 4X03 error
>
> SE 3X03 / CS 4X03 error - login.cpp
>
> Internal Error  3

Here is my code:

```
import requests

s = requests.session()

login_data = {
    'sno':'xxxxxxx',
    'p1':'xxxxxxx',
    'login':'OK'
}

reqheader = {

    'Host'  :'www.cas.mcmaster.ca',
    'User-Agent' :  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0',
    'Accept'  : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding'  :    'gzip, deflate',
    'Referer'   :   'http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~franek/courses/se3x03_cs4x03/login/startlogin.cgi',
    'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type'  :  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length'    :  '33'
}


myurl = 'http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~franek/courses/se3x03_cs4x03/login/login.cgi'

r = s.post(myurl, data = login_data, headers = reqheader)



print r.text
```

Can anyone pls give me a hint about where i did wrong? i appreciate it.

**EDIT:**

In the page source code there's a line:

```
<form name="passwd" action="http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~franek/courses/se3x03_cs4x03/login/login.cgi"
method="post">
```

Which is what httpFox has detected for me, and i think this is the actual log in link. But when i try to reach that url in my browser i get sth like this:

> SE 3X03 / CS 4X03 error - login.cpp
>
> Internal Error 11

Could this be the reason why my code didnt work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually see that `login.cpp` used under the hood, it is [available online](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~cs721/login/login.cpp).

The interesting part is where `Internal Error 3` happens:

```
  p=line;
  if (strncmp(p,"sno=",4)==0) {
    p += 4; // eat 'sno='
    if (*p=='&') { // no sno value
      p++; // eat &
    }else{
      q=p+1;
      while(! (*q=='&' || *q=='\0')) q++;
      if (*q=='\0') error("Internal error 2");
      *q='\0';
      if (strlen(p)>99) error("Internal error 3");
      translate(snobuf,p);
      p=q+1; // eat '.....&'
    }
```

As you can see, HTTP parameters are parsed manually from a raw string. There is an assumption that `&` is a parameter delimiter.

So what you need to do is to pass what it wants to be passed in. And no need to provide any special headers or handle cookies:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
data = 'sno={sno}&p1={p1}&login=+OK+'.format(sno=1234567, p1='Password')

myurl = 'http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~franek/courses/se3x03_cs4x03/login/login.cgi'
r = s.post(myurl, data=data)
print r.content
```

Since `1234567` and `Password` are not valid, I'm getting an HTML code with an error inside:

```
Student number not found, please re-enter
```

Use valid credentials and you'll get in.

Comment: *You can actually see that login.cpp used under the hood, it is available online.* - haha this is awsome.

Comment: @ReutSharabani they are quite secure, yeah :)

Comment: "You can actually see that login.cpp used under the hood". I dont get this part. how did you find the cpp file? I'm trying to reach it myself.

Comment: @Jackddddd, you should tell whoever is in charge there that anyone can get in using any password he wants. If you use the link @alecxe put here you get the `login.cpp` file... But you practically get everything.

Comment: @Jackddddd completely agree with ReutSharabani - it is a big security issue. The source code, especially like this, should not be allowed to viewed by everyone. How did I find it? I don't know - curiosity :)

Comment: @ReutSharabani Okay, this is beyond my knowledge scope.  how can one gets in using any password he wants. I cannot log in if my password is wrong.

Comment: Generally speaking the site is not cofigured properly. I sent a mail to the admin, he should change some configurations. Right now this site is broken and anyone can just grab all it's members' passwords. More specifically: The site displays just about any file that resdes on the server, and the everything (as well as the passwords and code) is in a file.